# FT-TS how to flatten the left side of TaskEither

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

Given the following bits:

`OnRequestSuccess` is a async function that does some work and returns a string
`OnRequestFailure` is a async function that does some work and returns a ERROR

This is somewhat the desiredFlow. I reckon I could make the fold call the asyncMethods, but then I am left with `TaskEither<Promise,Promise>` and I just want the final types.

```
pipe(input,chain(asyncRequestChatMessage), map(asyncOnRequestSuccess), mapLeft(asyncOnRequestFail),foldW(toTask,toTask), finalCall)
```

By the end of the chain I want to grab whatever was outputed from either (so a Task) and call a another async function with it.

My problem is that since both OnError and OnRequest are async, and I cant seem to make them resolve inside the flow. How do we do this?

Example code:

```
    const success = (result: string) => TE.tryCatch(() => onRequestSuccess(result), E.toError);
    const fail = (result: Error) => TE.tryCatch(() => onRequestFail(result), E.toError);


 // This is the problem

    const result = pipe(input, TE.right, TE.chain(requestChatMessage), TE.map(success), TE.mapLeft(fail), TE.flattenW);
```

The `FlattenW` solves the right side, but there isnt a `flattenLeftW` and I cant get `orElse` to work either.

In the example above how can I get by the end of it either a TASK of both types (onRequestSuccess and OnRequestFail) that I can then chain into another call?

Or how can I flatten the Left side of the TaskEither, since right now this returns

```
const result: TE.TaskEither<Error | TE.TaskEither<Error, Error>, string>
```

It feels I am missing something here really obvious

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly trying to do. `Either` represents a synchronous computation that can be a `Left` or `Right` value . `Task` represents a computation that will be solved in a future (similar to a `Promise` but "never" fails). `TaskEither` represents an asynchronous computation that once it's solved the result is of type `Either` (it's the same as a `Task<Either<L,R>>`). You have different ways of chaining operations. It's not clear for me how your operations work. Could you describe at a high level what you need? Looks like you are trying to make it work by force

Comment: The [suffix `W` means `Widen`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/code-conventions.html#what-a-w-suffix-means-eg-chainw-or-chaineitherkw). It is used when you chained different types of  `TaskEither.left`.

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain a bit better.

I am trying to build a "flow/pipeline" of operations that I want to execute in sequence, but by the end of the sequence of TE, I want to execute the same async function in both the left/right and return a single value out of it. I cant seem to get this to work, but I am probably doing something wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "**want to execute the same async function in both the left/right**"? [either](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html) represents an operation that will have a result of type right or left. once the either operation is processed, you have a result of left or right.

Answer (score 1):

orElse should do what you want, which is to function as chainLeft.

For example with contrived types:

```
type R = () => TE.TaskEither<'FAILURE', 'SUCCESS'>    
const success: R = () => TE.right('SUCCESS')
const failure: R = () => TE.left('FAILURE')
const requestChatMessage: R = () => TE.right('SUCCESS')

const result: TE.TaskEither<'FAILURE', 'SUCCESS'> = pipe(
    0, 
    TE.right, 
    TE.chain(requestChatMessage), 
    TE.chain(success),
    TE.orElse(failure),
)
```